# Passing JavaScript array to c/c++ library and back efficiently

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig, v8, node-gyp

Hi basically what I want to do is passing a JavaScript array to a c module function, then the function modify the array in place, then JavaScript reads the modified array.

Current approach is use `carrays.i` and `array_functions`, create and converting `Array` to and from `doubleArray` and due to copying array, its giving me result worse than native JS. My array have about **41000** items.

C module: **~10ms**(actual C function running time ~0.1ms)

JS module: **~3ms**

For me, it's not possible to use `doubleArray` from very beginning (as this is a part of a larger process). So the question is how can I improve it? Is it possible to use `TypedArray`/`ArrayBuffer`? If yes then how?

following is my pseudo code

```
let cArray = MyCModule.new_doubleArray(array.length),
    outArray = new Array(array.length);
arrayCopyJS2C(cArray, array);//written in JS and use a lot of time
MyCModule.MyCFunction(cArray, array.length);
arrayCopyC2JS(cArray, outArray);//also written in JS and use a lot of time
```

Comment: Why not use native JS? Round trip to server sounds like a weak link to me.

Comment: Have you tried using a [`Float64Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float64Array) in JavaScript?

Comment: Why are you copying the array? And why are you doing that in JS?

Comment: @Taylor Because I want to improve the running time

Comment: @Bergi Yes tried `Float64Array` and it's buffer(`MyFloat64Array.buffer`), well we are developing in nodejs, so we are doing everything in js.

Comment: @BensonChang Well the C module isn't js, is it? Are you saying that you cannot rewrite it and have to do everything in JS? Then please link the docs of the C module and show us the code you used to do your performance tests.

Comment: Can you show a minimal, complete example of what you've got right now? Having never used node.js, but being familiar with SWIG that'd make it much easier for me to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using an `ArrayBuffer` (with externalized backing store) is an efficient way to share a (number) array between JavaScript and C, because it doesn't require you to copy things around. That's assuming that you can use a `TypedArray` "from the beginning" on the JavaScript side; if the same limitation applies as to using a `doubleArray` from the beginning and you'd still have to copy, then the benefit will be smaller or nonexistent (depending on how fast you've made accesses to your `doubleArray`).

That said, V8 generates highly efficient code for operations on number arrays. I'm finding it hard to believe that the same function takes either 3ms in JS or 0.1ms in C. Can you share your JS implementation? If a C implementation is 30x as fast, then I bet the JS implementation could be improved a lot to get pretty close to that. Array operations are usually dominated by the time it takes to actually get the elements from memory, and no language has a particular advantage at that.

Comment: I think you have a point here, actually after running the JS function for few more time it goes down to 0.7ms ish. Thank you. I'll format my code and put it on later if I got time. I found a way to remove copy using node js addon, haven't implement yet, for now I'll stick with JS.